# Is there a dummy notification daemon?

Tags: notification, wayland

(Ubuntu 22.04 wayland swaywm)

I am not interested in any notifications, so I uninstalled dunst. However, many apps are now making their own notifications in incredibly hacky ways e.g. making a popup window which is really annoying.

I'd like to know if there exists some kind of dummy notification daemon which appears to apps as a usual notification daemon but never actually displays anything to me?

P.S Dunst wasn't working anyway, notifications would appear and never disappear automatically and for some reason changing the config file didn't fix that. I didn't want fix this issue (and I'm not asking you to) so I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't involve reinstalling dunst and changing its config as it probably wont work for me.

Comment: something from `ps aux | grep noti`

Comment: @nobody 
root       87363  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    17:08   0:00 [kworker/0:0-kacpi_notify]

Comment: No daemon running. I have no experience with sway. But I think you have to deactivate notifications in the apps it self maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dummy notification daemon:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Derived from https://github.com/mk-fg/notification-thing/blob/6c298ea861327329b87116ac347a35d3bef6d7d2/notification_thing/daemon.py

from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
import dbus.service

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GLib, Gdk

dbus_props = dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE
dbus_iface = 'org.freedesktop.Notifications'

class NotificationDaemon(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self, bus):
        dbus.service.Object.__init__( self, bus,
            '/org/freedesktop/Notifications', dbus.service.BusName(dbus_iface, bus) )

    @dbus.service.method(dbus_iface, '', 'ssss')
    def GetServerInformation(self):
        return 'dummy-notification-daemon', '1503864_1004020@askubuntu.com', '1.0', '1.0'

    @dbus.service.method(dbus_iface, '', 'as')
    def GetCapabilities(self):
        return ['body', 'persistence', 'icon-static']

    @dbus.service.signal(dbus_iface, 'uu')
    def NotificationClosed(self, nid, reason=None):
        pass

    @dbus.service.signal(dbus_iface, 'us')
    def ActionInvoked(self, nid, action_key):
        pass

    @dbus.service.method(dbus_props, 'ss', 'v')
    def Get(self, iface, k):
        raise KeyError

    @dbus.service.method(dbus_props, 's', 'a{sv}')
    def GetAll(self, iface):
        return []

    @dbus.service.method(dbus_props, 'ssv', '')
    def Set(self, iface, k, v):
        pass

    @dbus.service.signal(dbus_props, 'sa{sv}as')
    def PropertiesChanged(self, iface, props_changed, props_invalidated):
        pass

    @dbus.service.method(dbus_iface, 'susssasa{sv}i', 'u')
    def Notify(self, app_name, nid, icon, summary, body, actions, hints, timeout):
        return 0

    @dbus.service.method(dbus_iface, 'u', '')
    def CloseNotification(self, nid):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()

    daemon = NotificationDaemon(bus)
    loop = GLib.MainLoop()
    loop.run()
```

Save it to a `dummy_notifications_server.py` file, mark as executable, and run or add to autostart. I tested that this satisfies `notify-send`.